# Onedrive API rejects access token (CompactToken parsing failed with error code: 8004920A)

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

Hopefully I'm missing something very simple. According to [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/getting-started/msa-oauth?view=odsp-graph-online#token-flow) to get an access token I need to hit the following url:

```
https://login.live.com/oauth20_authorize.srf?client_id={client_id}&scope={scope}
&response_type=token&redirect_uri={redirect_uri}
```

So far this appears to be working as the returned url I get contains

```
/#access_token=EwAYA61DBAAUcSSzo.......
```

According to the token flow documentation above,

> You can use the value of access_token to make requests to the OneDrive API.

According to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/getting-started/?view=odsp-graph-online) page,

> Your app provides the access token in each request, through an HTTP header:
>
> Authorization: bearer {token}

When running curl I give it the exact token I was given before,

```
curl -X GET \
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drive \
-H 'Authorization: Bearer EwAYA61DBAAUcSSzoTJJs.....

{
"error": {
    "code": "InvalidAuthenticationToken",
    "message": "CompactToken parsing failed with error code: 8004920A",
    "innerError": {
        "request-id": "8780c600-2b7f-45a0-b484-7eca9dfd2697",
        "date": "2019-01-25T19:33:22"
    }
  }
}
```

Why is the token they provided not working?

What I've tried so far:

- changing the case of bearer in the header
- wrapping said token in {}
- generating new tokens
- URL decoding said token

One thing to note: the tokens I am receiving are *not* JWT tokens. Googling the error code pulls up several Stack Overflow questions that seem to imply the graph api is expecting a JWT. If this is the case, am I missing a step to obtaining it?

Comment: What happens if you try the [authorization with Microsoft Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/getting-started/graph-oauth?view=odsp-graph-online)? The authentication with Microsoft Account [is no longer recommended according the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/getting-started/msa-oauth?view=odsp-graph-online#use-microsoft-graph).

Comment: That did the trick. I knew it had to be something simple. Since the page you linked looked almost identical to the page I was using, I thought they were the same. @xilopaint if you post your comment as an answer I'll upvote and accept it.

Comment: xilopaint is correct - calls to Graph will not work with tokens obtained from the above endpoint. @xilopaint, can you create an answer with what you said? I'll upvote it for you :)

Comment: @brad answer posted. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't call Microsoft Graph API after completing the authentication flow for Microsoft accounts (OneDrive personal).

In addition, the authorization process with Microsoft accounts is no longer recommended [according the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/getting-started/msa-oauth?view=odsp-graph-online) and new applications should be developed using Microsoft Graph:

> This topic contains information about authorizing an application using Microsoft accounts for OneDrive personal. However, this approach is no longer recommended. New applications should be developed using Microsoft Graph and follow the authorization process in [Authorization and sign-in for OneDrive in Microsoft Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/getting-started/graph-oauth?view=odsp-graph-online).

Comment: what is to be used for OneDrive personal with Microsoft accounts? My code works for OneDrive for business cases. When trying to obtain a token in the Microsoft Graph API way, the token I get is not a JWT token and cannot be parsed as such. This same token passed as received (unparsed) as bearer to the OneDrive Graph API doesn't work and returns the same error as op. More so, how can the kind of token retrieved using the Microsoft account (deprecated) way be used to communicate with OneDrive personal?